# PHP fails silently when function not defined?

Tags: php

I am migrating from PHP4 to PHP5

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2039
```

Which used to show all errors.

I am still getting some errors but I used to get an error when I called a function that was not defined, but now it stops where it is at and send the client everything up to the error and nothing after. With no error message.

Here is what phpinfo is telling me:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
display_errors  On  Off
error_reporting 2039    6143
```

I would like to be able to see my error messages for trouble shooting purposes.

Can someone tell me what I need to do? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show the full PHP script? It could be that it terminates with a parse error, which indeed isn't caught by the error handler.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) in your php ?

Comment: OK so as it turns out I was including a page that had error_reporting(!E_NOTICE); at the top of it, (but my current page did not say this, just the included page). I can understand now why this would prevent my error from showing but what I find very curious is why this only started being an issue now that I moved to php5 and never caused problems when I was on php4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If everything fails, just put this code at the beginning of your (/of each) script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: I *think* I know this man! :D Willkommen, alter. Ich hab im Postausgang noch eine Mail an dich mit dem Tipp, mal hier reinzuschauen...

Comment: @Pekka: That is very personal and alien language :)

Comment: @Sarfraz just this once :) He is a colleague and mate of mine who I've been meaning to invite here for a long time (but ended up here independently from me now).

Comment: @Pekka: That is good to know, interestingly i have been inviting my friends but yet I have not found one.

Comment: Obviously I can earn much more reputation by answering php related questions than by helping some cocoa heads ;-)

Hi Pekka ;)

Comment: @unset hi! :) Yeah, the PHP tag is definitely more popular than the iPhone one. But the real prize, if you're after reputation, is in C#, java and .net (see the "tags" page)... Anyway. I'm sure you'll like it here.

Comment: Oh yeah, I like it here. The last few weeks I learned so much from this site … I felt like give something back. And the concept is as simple as exciting :D

Comment: It definitely is. To reach me in a comment directly, you need to address me using @Pekka btw so it pops up (Vote here if you want that changed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you) :)

Answer (score 1):

This should show you all messages:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you PHP 5 version is >= PHP 5.2.0 and that the original error reporting level was `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` (or `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`, both have the same result).

Prior to PHP 5.2.0 `E_ALL` had a value of `2047`, so your error level was `2039` due to not including the `E_NOTICE` level (of `8`).  As of PHP 5.2.0 `E_ALL` changed to `6143` (and as of PHP 5.3.0 to `30719`) which means `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` is no longer `2039`, but rather `6135` (or `30711` in PHP 5.3).

As for not displaying the errors (calling an undefined function should be a fatal error!), see the other answers.

Comment: So basically it looks like I will always need my error level to be Max-8. I wonder if there is a way to express this in .htaccess