# PHP header and refresh not working

Tags: php, header, refresh

My server running in **PHP 5.2.9**, When I using **refresh and header** functions it's not working. Here is my code

```
header("location: index.php");

header( "Refresh: 0;" );
```

Previously I'm working in a different server, It's working correctly. How can I solve this problem?

this is my complete code

```
if($_POST['sign_in'])
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE m_email='$email' and m_password='$password'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($count==1)
    {
        session_register("email");
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_temp_members WHERE email='$email'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
        if($count==1)
        {
            echo "Login unsuccessful,Account still not activated";  
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Login unsccessful";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have output before calling `header`? Do you have error reporting activated? Can you check for errors (warnings too)?

Comment: SQL injection FTW. :) Never mind the redirect. Fix that first.

Comment: I append full code to the question.

Comment: With the risk of repeating myself. Have you checked the error logs? My bet is that you get a MySQL error, but I can't be sure.

Comment: No errors, I uploaded same script to different server. It's working. But here not working.

Comment: I found a solution by myself

`echo ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">');`

Comment: @Sassi That's not a solution. It's a hack.

Comment: @ alin : opz. why u said like that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Location and Refresh both [require an absolute URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) (and it's "Location" instead of "location").

Try this one:

```
header('Location: http://absolute.uri/file.ext');
```

If that does not help, check [my answer for any "strange" PHP problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851633/php-fails-silently-when-function-not-defined/2851644#2851644) ;)

Comment: While you are right about the syntax, I doubt that is the problem. Unless he uses a very obscure browser.

Comment: @RRStoyanov "Citation please!" :) http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30 My sources say it **does** need to be absolute.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, Alin

Comment: Well, ok... by documentation you are right, by practice it may not be absolute, because all browsers nowadays have support for relative urls.

Comment: @RRStoyanov Hence my first comment on this. But that doesn't make it "wrong". It's just not very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to cause a redirect ? If this is the case you could simply use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` but if you want to refresh after a certain amount of time you can use:

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" ); 
echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 5 secs. ';
echo 'If not, click <a href="wherever.php">here</a>.';
```

Got the example code from - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - maybe worth a read too.

Answer (score 1):

(1) you don't need the refresh header if you have the location one

(2) add `exit;` in the end

> The second special case is the
>   "Location:" header. Not only does it
>   send this header back to the browser,
>   but it also returns a REDIRECT (302)
>   status code to the browser unless the
>   201 or a 3xx status code has already
>   been set.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I dont know what is the wrong. This is not working in this new server. :-(

Comment: Again, while you do give useful advice, it doesn't help solve his problem.

Comment: @Alin I just point to documentation this time so he can have some view. It's a bit hard when he didn't provide the code before `header`

Answer (score 0):

Then better use JavaScript for that. Append this code before :

```
<script> setTimeout(function() { window.location = "index.php"; }, 2000); </script>
```

Comment: worked for me I put the line in the <head> </head> . because php code didn't work for me.